# Axios uncaught error during setting stripe payments at Next.js, Error message: (AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500)

Tags: next.js, axios, stripe-payments, server-side-rendering

checkout.js page
contain all the code, I don't know what is missing, it gives axios error

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectItems } from '../slices/basketSlice';
import CheckoutProduct from '../components/CheckoutProduct';
import Currency from 'react-currency-formatter';
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import { selectTotal } from '../slices/basketSlice';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import axios from 'axios';

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.stripe_public_key);

function Checkout() {
  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  const total = useSelector(selectTotal);
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const createCheckoutSession = async() => {
    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    // Call the backend to create checkoutsession
    const checkoutSession = await axios.post('/api/create-checkout-session', {
      items: items,
      email: session.user.email,
    });
    // Redirect user to Stripe checkout
    const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: checkoutSession.data.id,
    })
    if(result.error){
      alert(result.error.message)
    };
  }
  return (
  <div className='bg-gray-100'>
    <Head>
        <title>Checkout</title>
    </Head>
    <Header/>
    <main className='lg:flex max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto'>
      <div className='flex-grow m-5 shadow-sm'>
        <Image
          src='https://links.papareact.com/dyz'
          width={1020}
          height={250}
          objectFit='contain'
          className='cursor-pointer'
          alt='image'
        ></Image>

        <div className='flex flex-col p-5 space-y-10 bg-white'>
          <h1 className='text-3xl border-b pb-4 font-bold'>
              {items.length === 0 ? 'Your Basket is Empty' : 'Shopping Basket'}
          </h1>

          {items.map((item, i) => (
            <CheckoutProduct
              key={i}
              id={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              rating={item.rating}
              price={item.price}
              description={item.description}
              category={item.category}
              image={item.image}
              hasPrime={item.hasPrime}
            >
            </CheckoutProduct>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-col bg-white p-10 shadow-md'>
        {items.length > 0 && (
        <>
          <h2 className='whitespace-nowrap'>Subtotal ({ items.length } items):
            <span className='font-bold'>
              <Currency quantity={total} currency='USD'></Currency>
            </span>
          </h2>
          <button role='link'
            onClick={createCheckoutSession}
            disabled={!session}
            className={`btn-1 mt-2 ${!session && 'btn-2 cursor-not-allowed'}`}>
            {!session ? 'Sign In to Checkout' : 'Proceed to Checkout'}
          </button>
        </>
        )}
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
  )
}

export default Checkout
```

## **ap/create-checkout-session.js Page**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
export default async(req, res) =>{
  const { items, email } = req.body;
  // console.log( items );
  // console.log( email );
  const transformedItems = items.map((item) => ({
      price_data: {
        currency: 'usd',
        unit_amount: item.price * 100,
        product_data: {
          name: item.title,
          images: [item.image]
        },
      },
      description: item.description,
      quantity: 1,
  }));

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA', 'GB'],
    },
    // shipping_rates: ['3.58'],
    line_items: transformedItems,
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${process.env.HOST}/success`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.HOST}/checkout`,
    metadata: {
      email,
      images: JSON.stringify(items.map((item) => item.image))
    },
  })

  res.status(200).json({ id: session.id })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Next. js will automatically return a 500 status code for an unexpected
> application error.

you make a request to `api/create-checkout-session.js`. code inside here is failing so next.js is returning 500 code. That code should be in `try/catch` block so you can see the exact error in `catch` block. you should `console.error(error)` in catch block.

Check https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create docs to pass correct parameters. those parameters changed recently make sure you use the correct version of stripe.

Also make sure you are passing correct environment variables. console.log all of them to see if they are correct